# Is the "Label" band from Dynamic World incomplete?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I am trying to calculate the water area of Dead Sea over time. The first experiment that I did was to visualize the "Water" from the "Label" band provided by Dynamic World:

```
var startDate = '2019-01-21';
var endDate = '2022-01-05';

var dw = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
               .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
               .filterBounds(geometry);
  
Map.centerObject(geometry, 12);

var classification = dw.select('label');

Map.addLayer(classification.first().clip(geometry).eq(0), {}, 'first of classification');
```

But yet, when I drew a rectangle around the Dead Sea, only the lower half is pixelated:

[image]

I have tried some other water body, it worked better, but still missing some corners:

[image]

So how can I please get the water label over all the water surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not incomplete. In your dates range there are probably about 3,900,000 images and you selected a little portion of the dynamic change: only the first image. Following [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e7a549089bb1707db26a4d3bd7ed7acc) considers a geometry in your Dead Sea area. First of all, it prints the number of images for the first month in your dates range. There are 108,437 images.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[35.08223965969702, 31.882488737725048],
          [35.08223965969702, 30.737384136692008],
          [35.91170743313452, 30.737384136692008],
          [35.91170743313452, 31.882488737725048]]], null, false);

var startDate = '2019-01-01';
var endDate = '2019-02-01';

var dw_month = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
               .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

print("dw_month count", dw_month.size());

var startDate = '2019-01-01';
var endDate = '2022-01-01';

var dw = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
               .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

var classification = dw.select('water');

var nMonths = ee.Number(ee.Date(endDate).difference(ee.Date(startDate),'month')).round();
var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0,nMonths).map(function (n) {
    var ini = ee.Date(startDate).advance(n,'month');
    var end = ini.advance(1,'month');
    return classification.filterDate(ini,end)
                  .select(0).mean()
                  .set('system:time_start', ini);
}));

var byMonth_lst = byMonth.toList(byMonth.size());

print(byMonth_lst);

Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(byMonth_lst.get(0)).clip(geometry), {}, 'first of classification');
// Visualization parameters.
var args = {
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',  
  dimensions: '500',
  region: geometry,
  framesPerSecond: 1
};

var text = require('users/gena/packages:text'); // Import gena's package which allows text overlay on image

var annotations = [
  {position: 'left', offset: '1%', margin: '1%', property: 'label', scale: 500}
  ];
  
function addText(image){
  
  var timeStamp = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format().slice(0,10); // get the time stamp of each frame. This can be any string. Date, Years, Hours, etc.
  timeStamp = ee.String('Date: ').cat(ee.String(timeStamp)); //convert time stamp to string 
  image = image.visualize({ //convert each frame to RGB image explicitly since it is a 1 band image
      forceRgbOutput: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 1,
      palette: ['midnightblue', 'blue', 'mediumblue', 'aqua', 'lime', 'limegreen', 'yellow','sandybrown', 'orange', 'crimson']
    }).set({'label':timeStamp}); // set a property called label for each image
  
  var annotated = text.annotateImage(image, {}, geometry, annotations); // create a new image with the label overlayed using gena's package

  return annotated;
}

var collection = byMonth.map(addText) //add time stamp to all images
  

print(ui.Thumbnail(collection,args));
```

As the number of images is so elevated, above script produces a mean image (by using "water" band; not "label" band) for each month in your dates range. It can be visualized in Map Canvas of GEE varying the integer number in following parameter **byMonth_lst.get(0)** (you can also use a function for loading all images at once).

However, the best way to display everything at once is by using an **ui.Thumbnail** object. The water area of Dead Sea over time, each month, it can be appreciated in following picture; where date associated with the monthly mean image, inside red rectangle, changes with the next image one frame per second.

[image]

Comment: In the thumbnail, does the color intensity represent the classification probability of "water"? When I reduced the palette to only two colors, I could still see different shades. Does it mean that thumbnail interpolate the colors for values between 0 and 1?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it correctly, you mean DW has the all the classifications. But because the image collection I requested was too large, EE did not display them all, like the upper half of Dead Sea in my case?

Comment: Yes. By the way, I took the monthly mean for getting quick results. However, you can mosaic images by day for obtaining only 0 and 1 values and, probably, a better result with a reduced palette to only two colors.

Comment: And the "no show" question please? Because of too many images, the upper half of Dead Sea did not show classification? Thanks.